# Messages seemingly disappearing with javax.mail

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am using the code from [this](https://www.educba.com/receiving-email-in-java/) tutorial with minimal modifications. Here is my code: `

```
public static void receiveEmail(String hst, String stype, String user, String password) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
            props.put("mail.pop3s.host", hst);
            props.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
            props.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            Store st = sess.getStore("pop3s");
            st.connect(hst, user, password);
            Folder emailFolder = st.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            
            Message message = messages[229];
            System.out.println("Welcome To Email");
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            String body = "body";
            Multipart part = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            MimeBodyPart mimePart = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < part.getCount(); i++) {
                mimePart = (MimeBodyPart) part.getBodyPart(i);
                System.out.println(mimePart.getContent());
                System.out.println("========");
            }
            
            emailFolder.close(false);
            st.close();
        }// catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

`

I am calling receive email from a driver class.  This is literally the only  method being called.

I will run the code and it will work fine, printing the contents of the 229th email. Then, if i run it again, with not changes whatsoever, I get an array index out of bounds exception saying index 229 is out of bounds for length 229.  As I understand it, when i run it, the code works fine, but somehow the email I want to access is no longer accessible. I have been trying to access the last email for testing purposes and I knew which number it is. What I think is happening is that the code is making the email I just accessed unavailable.  I just added a print line and confirmed that when i first run it, the length is such that the message being accessed is the last element in the array, upon running the program again, the array is mysteriously one element smaller. I have verified that the emails are actually not disappearing from my account. I think i started at email 250 or something and have been gradually losing access.  Another interesting thing to note is that yesterday, I was working with a different email account that only had 19 emails in it, after a short period of time, I was suddenly unable to list out the emails in that account with code.  The emails were there, I could send emails with code, but not access the emails stored on that account.

Comment: Wild guess:  do you think this could have something to do with the array length you have declared?  messages[229]  0 - 228 will fit in that?

Comment: The problem is that the array length is inexplicably changing when it should not.  I an not receiving or sending or deleting any emails.  For example the code prints out an email with a certain subject and I can see it in my inbox.  Then, two seconds later, I run the code again and it can't find the email, but it is still there.

Comment: What are you using to check besides your code.   Some application delete messages off the mail server when they download them.

Comment: The way I know that the emails are still there is by accessing my Gmail account through gmail.com in brave browser.